# Añadir el orden secuencial de cada identidad

Tags: r

A partir de una tabla como esta (la real tiene 66516filas).

```
  Prueba:
    Paciente    Valor      Fecha
      22          4     20/06/1993
      293         4     25/06/1993
      293         4     26/06/1993
      293         1     26/06/1993
      385         5     20/06/1993
      385         4     25/06/1993
```

Obtener una tabla con una columna nueva que aparezca el orden secuencial para cada paciente

```
    Paciente    Valor      Fecha      ID
      22          4     20/06/1993    1
      293         4     25/06/1993    1
      293         4     26/06/1993    2 
      293         1     26/06/1993    3
      385         5     20/06/1993    1
      385         4     25/06/1993    2
```

Para ello he probado con el siguiente código, pero sin éxito:

```
    PRUEBA$ID<-PRUEBA %>%
       group_by(Paciente) %>%
        rep(1:66516,len=66516)
```

También he probado el siguiente código, pero sin éxito:

```
       for(i in unique(PRUEBA$Paciente)) {
          PRUEBA$observation <- 1:nrow(PRUEBA)
       }
```

¿Cual es mi fallo? ¿Cómo podría solucionarlo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya que estas usando `dplyr` la forma más común es agrupar y usar [`row_number()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/ranking.html):

```
PRUEBA$ID <-PRUEBA %>%
       group_by(Paciente) %>%
       mutate(ID = row_number())
```

Conviene siempre tener presente el orden, los numeradores son dependientes del mismo, en este ejemplo mantenemos el orden "natural", pero nunca está de más ordenar previamente los datos con `arrange()`

Con R base podrías usar [`ave()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/ave) indicando columna de orden, columna de grupo y la función a aplicar:

```
df$ID <- ave(df$Fecha, df$Paciente, FUN = seq_along)
```

Comment: El script funciona genial. Toda la razón Patricio, previamente lo ordené, lo único que por no dar sobreinformación no lo he puesto. PRUEBA<-PRUEBA[order(PRUEBA$Paciente,PRUEBA$Fecha),]